# Вывод (ошибка NaN).Maxlength

Tags: jquery, javascript

Решение.

```
   var self = this;
   var maxLength = [];
   $("[maxlength]").each(function () {
       maxLength.push(parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength')));
     });
   $('#title_book').keyup(function()
   {
    self.keyupListener($('#title_book'), 0);
    //$('#sub').enabled = self.tryLength();
    })
   $('#annot_book').keyup(function()
   {
    self.keyupListener($('#annot_book'), 1);
   })
   $('#descr_book').keyup(function()
   {
    self.keyupListener($('#descr_book'), 2);
   })
this.keyupListener = function(elem, idx) {
    var curLength = $(elem).val().length;
    $(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength[idx]));
    console.log(parseInt(maxLength[idx]));
    var remaning = (parseInt(maxLength[idx])) - parseInt(curLength);
    if (remaning < 0) remaning = 0;
    $('#number_char' + idx).html(remaning + ' осталось символов');
    $('#number_value' + idx).css('display','block');
    $('#numberV' + idx).animate({'width': curLength+'%', }, 1);
    if (remaning < 10)
    {
        $('#number_char' + idx).addClass('warning');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#number_char' + idx).removeClass('warning');
    }

    return $(elem).attr('maxlength');
}

this.tryLength = function() {
    return $('#title_book').val().length > 2 && $('#annot_book').val().length > 2;
}
```

Comment: @El_ten, так на какую строчку ругается? также ссылка или фидл были бы полезны, мне например влом вникать в полотно кода вырванное с мясом, подозреваю не одному мне

Comment: @El_ten, эктрасенсы в отпуске. Вы хотите, чтобы мы определили ошибку по куску вырванному из контекста? Поставьте debugger перед проблемной строкой и смотрите, что там происходит.

Comment: индусский код в полный рост

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Исправленный и рабочий код (анимация тоже работает)](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9e56/2/)**

1) Не забывайте указывать основание системы счисления (2-й параметр функции), при использовании **parseInt**;
2) **Проверяйте наличие атрибута maxlength**
3) Проверяйте правильность селекторов;
4) Проверяйте правильность использования стилей;
5) Проверяйте правильность расстановки точек с запятой;
6) Если просите помощи, максимально подробно описывайте проблему, указывайте, что вы делали и что не получилось, старайтесь вычленить проблемный участок кода;
7) Правильная формула для прогресс бара:

- Убывающий: **(maxLength[idx] - curLength) / maxLength[idx] * 100 + '%'**
- Нарастающий: **100 - (maxLength[idx] - curLength) / maxLength[idx] * 100 + '%'**